# Data transfer between two Rpi over internet TCP IP

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, iot, remote-access

I am looking for an application that can transfer data (analogue or digital signals generated from control levers) from one Rpi(say Rpi A to which the levers are interfaced) to another Rpi(say Rpi B to which the motor is interfaced). The purpose of this application is to control the operation of an electric motor based on the control lever setting. The operation should not be affected by the distance between the two Rpis and hence i want this data to be transferred over internet.

How do i send data from Rpi A to Rpi B over internet without using any cloud storage services.

Please suggest any suitable methods on how to do the data transfer with any suitable / similar codes available with you.
Thanking You
With regards 
Arjun

Comment: Are the pies in the same network?

Comment: I have done it previously with the two rpis connected to the same wifi router (both in same LAN).Now i wish to do it in such a way that they use internet for connectivity such that the devices are accessible from anywhere. thank you for showing interest in this. Please share any info tht you have.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for libraries or software products are explicitly off topic on stackoverflow.  Besides even if they were not, your question would still be missing far too much critical detail - for example it is not even clear if the Internet service used by the two devices would permit them to be in direct contact at all, by hole-punching mediated by a server, or only by relaying traffic through a server.